# how to get this format 29-Jun-12 12:00:00 AM in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using the following for date picker control

```
$(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy",
            onSelect : function(date, picker) {
                getCasePackCalendar(date); // call you function here
            }
        });
    });
```

I want the date format to be like : `29-Jun-12 12:00:00 AM`
How to get this in jQuery?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can only get date with datepicker. Use [timepicker plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) with datepicker to get full date and time

Comment: do you want to get the current time, or you want to select time as date??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
      onSelect:function(date, picker)
        {               
            var currentdate = new Date();
            var hh = currentdate.getHours();
            var mm = currentdate.getMinutes();
            var ss = currentdate.getSeconds();
            var tt = "";

            if(hh >= 12)
            {
                tt = "P.M.";
                hh = hh-12;
            }
            else
            {
                tt = "A.M.";
            }       
            $(this).val(date+" "+hh+":"+mm+":"+ss+" "+tt);
        }
  });
```

Check this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/WC38m/7/

Comment: i don't want to hard code the time. I should get the present time. so not relevant answer.any way thanks.

Comment: I glad that you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat : "d-M-y",// Change the format
            onSelect : function(date, picker) {
                getCasePackCalendar(date);
            }
        });
    });
```

You can find datepicker's different date format [here](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html)

As for time, jquery datepicker does'nt support time, maybe you can try another plugin [like this](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/)

[Demo for date](http://jsfiddle.net/kGjdL/98/)